# Unix code is working only in one server

Tags: unix

Unix code below, is working only on one server. On other servers I am not getting any error but I am getting empty mail. What could be the possible issue with it?

```
( 
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT" 
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"  
 echo "Content-Type: text/html" 
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline" 
 cat $CONTENT ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```

Comment: You have made sure all servers actually have sendmail installed?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on "other servers" the variable `$CONTENT` is not set or does not name an existing file, or maybe references a non-existing directory.

Are you sure that `$CONTENT` has/causes an empty line between mail header and message body?

Comment: Everything is same on all the servers , I mean shell script

Comment: @somashaker No, not everything is the same. How is the script started? Is it run by cron? What is the `PATH` on each of the servers? Maybe `cat` is not in the `PATH`. Maybe the file named by `$CONTENT` is in fact empty (at least in the moment it is read by your script)?